# Appropriate econometric model for repeated cross sectionals

Tags: r, panel-data, multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model, cross-section

This is a question about repeated cross sectional and panel data analysis. I have scoured through related questions on this site and Stack Overflow but haven’t quite found what I am looking for.

**Data description**
The primary dataset contains yearly information on anonymous individuals’ gender, age range, income, occupation group, etc. from 2003 to 2015, inclusive.

[image: table_1]

A panel cannot be created as the IDs 1, 2, 3 … do not refer to the same individual over time.

In addition, a secondary dataset contains annual macroeconomic indicators such as GDP per capita and unemployment rates.

[image: table_2]

I then combined the disparate dataset into one table that has the following structure:

[image: table_3]

**Estimation objective**
The broad aim is to run a regression on Income using the other variables as explanatory variables and explicitly control for unobserved heterogeneity with respect to *year* (time effect) and *occupation_group* (group effect).

In other words, if this was a panel dataset, then I would preferably be running a two-way FE model.

**Question 1**
My first question is that, since this is a repeated cross sectional, is the closest model I can get to a two-way FE a LSDV?

In R codes

```
lm(Income ~ as.factor(Year) + as.factor(Occupation.group) + Gender + Age.range + GDP.per.capita + Unemployment.rate, data = data)
```

However, the above regression does not work because of perfect collinearity (singularity) between Year and the macro indicators GDP.per.capita and Unemployment.rate

**Question 2**
Would it be possible to retain both the Year effect as well as information such as yearly GDP per capita (and treat *GDP.per.capita* as numeric rather than as a factor in R’s parlance)?

Comment: Hi Juan, welcome to CV! On this site there's no need to say "thank you" at the end of your post - it might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site ([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and it means future readers of your question don't need to read through the pleasantries. Please edit your post.

Comment: Hi Jan, post edited as requested.